# What does ownership percentage in nodetool status refer to?

Tags: cassandra

What does the percentage ownership refer to in the "nodetool status " output? Is it the disk space or token distribution or anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `nodetool status` ownership refers to the amount of token data ownership for the node multiplied by the replication factor. As per the [documentation here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsStatus.html#toolsStatus__description)

> The percentage of the data owned by the node per datacenter times the
>   replication factor. For example, a node can own 33% of the ring, but
>   show 100% if the replication factor is 3.
>
> Attention: If your cluster uses keyspaces having different replication
>   strategies or replication factors, specify a keyspace when you run
>   nodetool status to get meaningful ownership information.

Disk space is covered by the `load` which excludes data in the snapshot directories. Again the same doc link covers this.

Answer (score 1):

Ownership defines how much data is owned by the node.

If you add up the ownerships of each node in a single datacenter it would add up to

```
100*RF percent
```

where RF is Replication Factor, which mean data have RF number of replicas in the datacenter.